# NDK get instance of AssetManager through JNIEnv (Xamarin.Android, C++)

Tags: c++, xamarin, android-ndk, native, jnienv

I'm writing a Xamarin Android App which contains a native C++ library.

That native library contains a function which should load an image via the assetmanager.

**C++**

```
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>

void showImage(JNIEnv* env)
{
    jclass clsAct = jniEnv->FindClass("android/app/Activity");

    //... missing code to get activity

    AAssetManager* assetManager = activity->assetManager;
    AAsset* assetFile = AAssetManager_open(assetManager, "image.txt", AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);

    //load image
}
```

That's as far as I got it. Somehow I need to get the activity in order to get access to the assetmanager to load the asset. Calling showImage works correctly, also `clsAct` is set after the call to FindClass, so I guess on that nothing is wrong.

**C#**

```
[DllImport("libAndroid", EntryPoint = "showImage")]
private static extern void ShowImage(IntPtr jniEnv);

//...

ShowImage(JNIEnv.Handle);

//...
```

How can I get access to the current activity on the C++ side through JNIEnv?

Comment: You can just pass the current Context (activity or application) via the Java handle to your C++ function

Comment: I'm in a Xamarin / C# environment (not Java), is there a way to get the Java handle?

Comment: `var appHandle = Application.Context.Handle;` or 
   `var activityHandle = this.Handle;`

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question already!